# Visualization/Verification software for interacting parts e.g. Gears etc

Tags: modeling, simulation, terminology

Not sure if there is any software that would model the movements of physical parts, or if even they can move with the given configurations ( software engineer background, no idea the lingo used here ).

For example, at the start  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdCX05flrWM) it shows modelling of gears simulated, do CAD programs have this capability or this is something else? are there programs that are able to determine if parts were made (for example) from plastic, then they would break, or if they were made of steel then they would require too much torque that the stepper motor wouldn't be able to handle.

Basically, what are the current limitations of modelling and simulation software for mechanical systems?